# has_messages analog Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, messaging

There is a realy simple gem has_messages for messaging between users.
But I have some troubles with this gem.
And seems to me he is not active anymore.
Can you give gem as simple as has_messages?

No need to use systems like Faye.

Answer (score 0):

acts-as-messageable is solution for me